How to model this button?
I've tried using a beveled plane, then inset the plane and extrude but I cant get it to match.


This is what I currently have: 

Can you add larger reference images please? At the moment it's difficult to see what your model is supposed to look like.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

What about using a metaball capsule instead, and reusing the rest of your process? That's kind of the shape you're going for, I believe. Just smooth and flatten it.

Create a 32 vertex circle, bevel its 2 opposite vertices:

Pull the bottom half to get this shape:

Fill with F, inset with i:

Create some loopcuts with CtrlR:

Bevel the new edge loops with CtrlB, create 3 cuts:

Pull up the inner edge:

Bevel it to get the round shape:

Or when you bevel, create 1 segment only:

Extrude up:

Bevel the top edges:

